# Change keyboard layout with r_shift and r_alt in Lubuntu(LXQt)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, lubuntu, lxde

I want change my keyboard layout, like <kbd>Windows</kbd> with right <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right <kbd>Alt</kbd>. But now just can one time change. left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + left <kbd>Alt</kbd> is working but right <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right <kbd>Alt</kbd> work for one time.

My settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way but this way worked for me.

Edit your secondary keyboard layout symbols language file in path:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

Example: for Persian(Iran) language:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ir
```

And **delete** all the following lines of code from the file:

```
include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

You can use Replace(Ctrl+H) option in your editor.

**reboot** at the end.